# Extracting all text between two HTML headings with lxml

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I'm trying to parse HTML page using lxml in Python.

In HTML have this structure:

```html
<html>
   <h5>Title</h5>
   <p>Some text <b>with</b> <i>other tags</i>.</p>
   <p>More text.</p>
   <p>More text[2].</p>

   <h5>Title[2]</h5>
   <p>Description.</p>

   <h5>Title[3]</h5>
   <p>Description[1].</p>
   <p>Description[2].</p>

   ***
   and so on...
   ***
</html>
```

I need to parse this HTML to following JSON:

```
[
   {
      "title": "Title",
      "text": "Some text with other tags.\nMore text.\nMore text[2].",
   },
   {
      "title": "Title[2]",
      "text": "Description.",
   },
   {
      "title": "Title[3]",
      "text": "Description[1].\nDescription[2]",
   }
]
```

I can read all h5 tags with titles and write them into JSON using this code:

```
array = []
for title in tree.xpath('//h5/text()'):
    data = {
        "title" : title,
        "text" : ""
    }
    array.append(data)

with io.open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    str_ = json.dumps(array,
                      indent=4, sort_keys=True,
                      separators=(',', ' : '), ensure_ascii=False)
    outfile.write(to_unicode(str_))
```

The problem is, I don't know how to read all of these paragraphs contents between `<h5>` headings and put em into `text` JSON field.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is to parse everything tag by tag and build JSON of it...

Answer (score 0):

To get all text "between" two elements, for example between two headings, there is no other way than this:

- walk the entire `tree` (we'll use `.iterwalk()` because we must make a distinction between start and end of elements)
- create a data item for each heading one encounters (let's call it the `current_heading`)
- collect into a list all the individual text bits of any other element that comes by
- every time a new heading is encountered, store the data collected so far and begin a new data item

Every element in ElementTree element can have a `.text` and a `.tail`:

```html
<b>This will be the .text</b> and this will be the .tail
```

We must collect both, otherwise text will be missing from the output.

The following keeps track of where we are in the HTML tree using a stack, so `.head` and `.tail` of nested elements are collected in the right order.

```
collected_text = []
data = []
stack = []
current_heading = {
    'title': '',
    'text': []
}
html_headings = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']

def normalize(strings):
    return ''.join(strings)

for event, elem in ET.iterwalk(tree, events=('start', 'end')):
    # when an element starts, collect its .text
    if event == 'start':
        stack.append(elem)

        if elem.tag in html_headings:
            # reset any collected text, b/c now we're starting to collect
            # the heading's text. There might be nested elements in it.
            collected_text = []

        if elem.text:
            collected_text.append(elem.text)

    # ...and when it ends, collect its .tail
    elif event == 'end' and elem == stack[-1]:

        # headings mark the border between data items
        if elem.tag in html_headings:
            # normalize text in the previous data item
            current_heading['text'] = normalize(current_heading['text'])

            # start new data item
            current_heading = {
                'title': normalize(collected_text),
                'text': []
            }
            data.append(current_heading)
            # reset any collected text, b/c now we're starting to collect
            # the text after the the heading
            collected_text = []

        if elem.tail:
            collected_text.append(elem.tail)

        current_heading['text'] = collected_text
        stack.pop()

# normalize text in final data item
current_heading['text'] = normalize(current_heading['text'])
```

When I run this against your sample HTML, I get this output (JSON formatted):

```
[
    {
        "text" : "\n   Some text with other tags.\n   More text.\n   More text[2].\n\n   ",
        "title" : "Title"
    },
    {
        "text" : "\n   Description.\n\n   ",
        "title" : "Title[2]"
    },
    {
        "text" : "\n   Description[1].\n   Description[2].\n\n   ***\n   and so on...\n   ***\n",
        "title" : "Title[3]"
    }
]
```

My `normalize()` function is very simple and retains all the newlines and other whitespace that is part of the HTML source code. Write a more sophisticated function if you want a nicer result.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way to do this, just keep track of the position of the next h5 and make sure you select p's with a lower position:

```
data = []

for h5 in doc.xpath('//h5'):
  more_h5s = h5.xpath('./following-sibling::h5')
  position = int(more_h5s[0].xpath('count(preceding-sibling::*)')) if len(more_h5s) > 0 else 999
  ps = h5.xpath('./following-sibling::p[position()<' + str(position) + ']')
  data.append({
    "title": h5.text,
    "text": "\n".join(map(lambda p: p.text_content(), ps))
  })
```

It might even be simpler still to just "follow" the `following-sibling::*` until it's no longer a `p`

Comment: This only works for `<p>`s though, and only if all text really is *inside* a `<p>`. Real-world documents are likely to be less than optimally structured.

Comment: You could change that p to whatever you want. Usually I will just follow the "next()" in a while loop but those are clumsy in python

Comment: Yeah, but that still won't cover text outside of `<p>` (or whatever). Also, `preceding-sibling` does not stop at the previous `<h5>`, so at the last `<h5>`, the `count(preceding-sibling::*)` will be *all* elements before that `<h5>`, so I'm not even sure how this whole `position` thing is supposed to work? (Other than that:  `'AttributeError: lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'text_content'`)

Comment: text outside of p or whatever can be selected with text(). `count(preceding-sibling::*)` will give the position of the element which you can use in your position() xpath expression. I'm using html from lxml.

Answer (score 0):

First, split the children of the element into individual sections based on the tag passed.

```
def split(element, tag):
    sections = [[]]
    for element in element:
        if element.tag == tag:
            sections.append([])
        sections[-1].append(element)
    return sections
```

From there, it can be reshaped into a dictionary. Something like the following should do:

```
data = []
for section in split(html, "h5"):
    if section and section[0].tag == "h5":
        data.append(
            {
                "title": section[0].text_content(),
                "text": "\n".join(q.text_content() for q in section[1:]),
            }
        )
```